# SQL Server - Select using CASE inside FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a `select` using `case` clause inside `from` but I didn't figure how can I do it.

Actually, this is how my select look like:

```
SELECT 
   a.UserId,   
   ISNULL(sent, 0) AS sent,  
   ISNULL(received,0) AS received
FROM        
   (SELECT 
       TT1.UserId as UserId, 
       SUM(TotalUsers) AS sent        
    FROM 
       #TableTemp1 TT1
    INNER JOIN 
       #TableTemp2 TT2 ON TT1.UserId = TT2.UserId
    WHERE 
       TT1.Status = -1
    GROUP BY 
       TT1.UserId) a        
LEFT JOIN    
      .....
```

I need to change the statement inside () for something this:

```
SELECT 
   a.UserId,   
   ISNULL(sent, 0) AS sent,  
   ISNULL(received, 0) AS received
FROM        
   (CASE TT1.ExportDate 
       WHEN IS NULL 
         THEN 
            SELECT
                TT1.UserId as UserId, TotalSent as sent 
            FROM SentData 
            INNER JOIN DataConsolidated DC on CDE.UserId = DC.UserId 
         ELSE
            SELECT 
                TT1.UserId as UserId, SUM(TotalUsers) AS sent        
            FROM #TableTemp1 TT1
            INNER JOIN #TableTemp2 TT2 ON TT1.UserId = TT2.UserId
            WHERE TT1.Status = -1
    GROUP BY TT1.UserId
       END) a        
 LEFT JOIN  
       ......
```

I know that i don't have 'TT1' when I call CASE but I'm kinda lost in SQL clauses.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Providing schema might help here, in terms of how efficient a solution we can help you achieve.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that can check a condition and return one value or another - it's **NOT** a flow-control statement that can execute code blocks and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was in a stored procedure, I would recommend putting your logic in a IF/ELSE block.  However, if you are doing an inline query, you might be better-off running both sets (with conditions that could result in an empty set) and then UNION the results.  Like this:

```
SELECT a.UserId,   
     ISNULL(sent,0) AS sent,  
     ISNULL(received,0) AS received
  FROM        
  (        
           SELECT TT1.UserId as UserId, TotalSent as sent 
           FROM SentData inner join DataConsolidated DC on CDE.UserId = DC.UserId 
           WHERE TT1.ExportDate IS NULL

           UNION

           SELECT TT1.UserId as UserId, SUM(TotalUsers) AS sent        
           FROM #TableTemp1 TT1
                INNER JOIN #TableTemp2 TT2 ON TT1.UserId = TT2.UserId
           WHERE TT1.Status = -1
             AND TT1.ExportDate IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY TT1.UserId
  ) a        
  LEFT JOIN  
       ......
```

Comment: Yes, it's a stored procedure..this select fill the values for a insert..something like

     insert into bla (a, b, c) values <select above>

Comment: Okay. That would have been good to mention in your question. This way still will work, but an IF/ELSE statement would be more efficient. Since you only posted part of your query (and not any INSERT syntax) it would be very difficult for me to give you good syntax for the other approach.

Comment: Basically, the syntax for a IF/ELSE has to be something like IF (condition) <INSERT statment> ELSE <alternative INSERT statement>. You cannot say INSERT (IF (condidion) <select statement> ELSE <alt select statement> ). That kind of syntax is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you are trying to achieve and where CDE comes from i geuss that is the allias for senddate?

But if you want to work with a case you need to put it inside your select. I Guess you are looking for something like this?

```
SELECT a.UserId,   
     ISNULL(sent,0) AS sent,  
     ISNULL(received,0) AS received
  FROM        
  (        

        SELECT tt1.userid
              case when TT1.ExportDate is null 
              then ( 
                     select TotalSent from SentData CDE
                     inner join DataConsolidated DC on CDE.UserId = DC.UserId
                     where tt1.userId = CDE.userid
                    ) 
              else SUM(TotalUsers)
              end AS sent        
        FROM #TableTemp1 TT1
            INNER JOIN #TableTemp2 TT2 ON TT1.UserId = TT2.UserId
        WHERE TT1.Status = -1
            GROUP BY TT1.UserId
end 
  ) a        
  LEFT JOIN  
       ......
```